# Is it possible to identify and distinguish types using Fortran's Select Type?

Tags: select, fortran

Can `Select Type` distinguish between `Integer(Int8)`, `Integer(Int16)`, `Integer(Int32)` and `Integer(Int64)`?

Also, can `Select Type` identify an integer type irrespective of the number of bits it uses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can write something like the following.  Here I'm using real kind constants from the intrinsic module `iso_fortran_env`.

```
SELECT TYPE(areal)
TYPE is (REAL(real32))
   WRITE(*,*) '... real32'
TYPE is (REAL(real64))
   WRITE(*,*) '... real64'
CLASS default
   WRITE(*,*) '... default'
END SELECT
```

Note, though, that you can't write

```
SELECT TYPE(areal)
TYPE is (REAL(real32))
   WRITE(*,*) '... real32'
TYPE is (REAL(real64))
   WRITE(*,*) '... real64'
TYPE is (REAL)
    WRITE(*,*) '... real'
CLASS default
   WRITE(*,*) '... default'
END SELECT
```

In this case a real of default kind (probably `real32` for most current compilers) will match two of the type guard statements, and that's an error the compiler should pick up.

Comment: Does `TYPE is (REAL)` match only Real(Real32)? How about `Double Precision`?

Comment: Of course it accepts an integer type, that's why you put `Integer` in there.

Comment: The clarification for the final part is good (I was going to comment pre-edit), but is it worth being more explicit?  `real32` is probably the default kind number, but if the default kind number is neither `real32` nor `real64` then the code snippet is allowed.  [I read the sentence as saying that default kind _is_ one of those two, but probably `real32`.]

Comment: Also `Type Is (Real (Real32))` accepts `Real`, and `Type Is (Real (Real64))` accepts `Double Precision`.

Comment: @Zeus that is the likely outcome, but not portable. Try to something as `-fdefault-real-8` (it is not against the standard!) and report back.

Comment: @Zeus don't forget that the storage sized based kinds introduced in Fortran2008 may not exist at all.

Comment: Using `-fdefault-real-8`, the consequence is that `Real` is picked up by `Type Is (Real(Real64))`.

Comment: @Zeus Exactly, but don't forget that this behavior can change from platform to platform and from compiler to compiler.

Answer (score 1):

Different integer kinds constitute different intrinsic types. So yes, `select type` distinguishes integers of different kinds.

I am not aware of any possibility to disregard the kind (i.e. not just the number of bytes, theoretically). You must use a distinct `type is` section for each kind.

Comment: Also note that there may be a kind number for an integer with 32 bit storage size that isn't `int32` (etc.).

Comment: @francesalus exactly, that is the meaning of the parenthesis, but maybe better to say it directly.

Comment: Indeed, I was agreeing with you, reinforcing that _if_ a mechanism existed to select based on storage size it wouldn't necessarily resolve to one kind.